# Windows Username using request.getRemoteuser() or request.getPrincipalUser() authentication issue

Tags: java, windows, kerberos

I have a requirement in which I need to send links to the user who has some requests pending at his role. When user clicks on that link, he can access the application skipping the login but for creating a session. I need to use the windows username. I tried using `system.getProperty("user.name")` but it is giving user name which is host dependent, which means giving username of a particular host. But I need the windows username of a user sending the request. I tried using `request.getRemoteUser()` and `getPrincipalUser()` but facing some authentication issues.

Can anyone help me regarding this issue?